# JSON return populates field, now need to apply that value to make select option selected

Tags: jquery

JSON - JQUERY
Here is what I get back from JSON return from my CFC

{"thename":"Disabled","displayname":"Currently Helium House Gas is Unavailable to select, contact xxxxxx@xxx.com for more information."}

My input name="thename" gets populated with the value "Disabled" all good...

Now I have a select

```
<SELECT id="Enablor" name="Enablor"> 
<OPTION value="Enabled">Enabled</option>
<OPTION value="Disabled">Disabled</option>
</SELECT>
```

I want to take the ---  "thename":"disabled"  if disabled make the option disabled selected
"thename":"enabled"   if enabled make the option enabled selected

It is only going to be one or the other.  I want to do this in my return sucess jquery.

```
$.ajax({             
url: "changedisablesysequipment.cfc?method=getName"
,cache: false
,dataType: "json"            
,data: {lastname: datas}
, success: function (data){
$("#frmMain").formHash(data);
alert($('#thename')[0]);// this just shows [object]
Want to make option selected here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to do in order to make an option selected is to add it this:

```
selected="selected"
```

To its attributes.

For example:

```
<SELECT id="Enablor" name="Enablor"> 
<OPTION value="Enabled" selected="selected">Enabled</option>
<OPTION value="Disabled">Disabled</option>
</SELECT>
```

I'm not a jQuery user, but probably something like:

```
$("#Enablor OPTION[value=" + data.thename + "]")[0].​selected = "selected"​​​​​
```